# Need help to point docker client to the docker daemon running on my laptop

Tags: docker, minikube

I am running minikube on my Macbook. in order to build a Dockerfile inside minikube (VM), I pointed my docker client to the minukube´s docker daemon using below command

eval $(minikube docker-env)

I was able to build the image successfully on minikube and I stopped the minikube when my job is done.

Now when I tried to run the command "docker images" I am getting below error

"Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://:. Is the docker daemon running?"

I would really appreciate any help to resolve this problem

Note : I figured it just lasts on the current session of the terminal. but still wondering is there any better way w/o closing the current session of the terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the Minikube documentation on the `docker-env` command [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/commands/docker-env/), or run the command with the `--help` flag like so:

```
$ minikube docker-env --help
Sets up docker env variables; similar to '$(docker-machine env)'.

Options:
      --no-proxy=false: Add machine IP to NO_PROXY environment variable
      --shell='': Force environment to be configured for a specified shell: [fish, cmd, powershell, tcsh, bash, zsh],
default is auto-detect
  -u, --unset=false: Unset variables instead of setting them

Usage:
  minikube docker-env [flags] [options]

Use "minikube docker-env options" for a list of global command-line options (applies to all commands).
```

you'll notice the `--unset` flag.

Try running:

```
$ eval $(minikube docker-env --unset)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Docker for Mac does not use a tcp connection to the daemon, but connects using a socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`); check if there's no `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable set in your shell that overrides the default connection.

It seems minikube overrides the default docker settings by setting these three variables

```
DOCKER_HOST=
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/some/certs
```

Please unset these and stopped  `minikube stop`  and that and docker for mac will start working.

```
eval "$(docker-machine env -u)"
```

It will unset the  `DOCKER_*`  variables.

For the record, here's the output of  `docker-machine env -u`:

```
unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
unset DOCKER_HOST
unset DOCKER_CERT_PATH
unset DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME
```

More information you can find here: [docker-mac](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2132), [docker-unset](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/348).

Comment: This one works for me too. really appreciate you help! Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you accept and upvote this answer to make it more visible for future community ?

Comment: I did upvote but it’s not visible as I’ve less than 15 badges